# How to show that the Restricted-3-color decision problem is in the polynomial class

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, coloring

I'm struggling to answer a past paper question, which asks to prove that the defined problem is in the polynomial complexity class(P). The question is mentioned below

[image]

The only strategy I can come up with for this question is to somehow reduce the problem to the 2-color decision problem(determine whether or not the vertices of a graph can be colour with two colours with no vertex adjacent to another vertex with the same colour), and I already know that the 2-color decision problem is in P.

The problem with this strategy is that I will need to drop one of my three colours in order to reduce the problem to a 2-color decision problem, also I can't feed the same graph into the 2-color algorithm(possibly by merging two colours into one, e.g replace blue and yellow, with green), since a graph containing triangles can be coloured using the restricted 3 colours, however any graph containing a triangle cannot be 2-colourable. So if my strategy is correct then how can I reconstruct my original graph so that it can be fed into the algorithm for the 2-color decision problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You can reduce the problem to 2-CNF-SAT.

Have clauses such as $B_{17}\lor R_{17}$, $\neg B_{17} \lor \neg R_{17}$, and $\neg B_{17}\lor \neg B_{42}$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand where you got the subscripts from

Comment: @AndrewBrick: Each variable name seems to consist of a letter (either R or B, and we might craftily assume that G is also an option) and a number. What would be a natural thing for the numbers to stand for?